# Why javascript (jquery) if statements does not work like php if statements? And what is solution?

Tags: jquery, if-statement

`JavaScript` code

```
var a = 0;//remove latter
var b = 1;

if (a > 0) {
alert ("a > 0");
}

if (b > 0) {
alert ("b > 0");
}
```

all works (`alert ("b > 0");`).

But if remove `var a = 0;`, then second `if` does not work.

So conclusion if for first `if` no variable, then second `if` does not work.

What is solution? Always define `javascript` - `jquery` variables? Like if no var a, then var a = 0;?

Comment: Your second condition is not executing because you have an error in your first condition.
The solution could be as you wrote is to define variables OR to use try/catch for error handling OR(this is my preferred solution) to check if variable is defined

Comment: Now I understand. Before supposed that `jquery if` works like `php if`. `php if` would execute in such situation

Comment: Also it is worth mentioning that your code is pure JavaScript code and not JQuery code and there is no "jQuery if behavior" !

Comment: Yes, in question, yes. It is JavaScript. I shortened code for the question. Will correct title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the variable is not declared then javascript throws an [ReferenceError](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ReferenceError), so any variable that will be used within javascript evaluation must be declared.

It is be bahaviour as per [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.7.1) which says

> If IsUnresolvableReference(V), throw a ReferenceError exception.

So yes the variables has to be declared like `var a, b` even though it is not initialized with any value.

Answer (score 3):

If you remove a variable, the javascript faces to an error(ReferenceError), so it won't execute the rest of code buddy.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why it does not work is because you do not have an `a` variable defined anymore, and you are breaking the javascript with an undefined variable. If you remove

```
if (a > 0) {
alert ("a > 0");
}
```

the rest of the code should work.

Answer (score 2):

If you remove definition of `a` variable, you get an error:

```
ReferenceError: a is not defined
```

and your script will be stopped.